# How to know the time and space complexity of the following snapshot?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I understand how the code in the following snapshot works but I am curious how would I know the time and space complexity of it?

I know it depends on the time it takes for 'b' to become zero. Is there some mathematical way that I can find this?
I understand that this wont go into millions of recursions ever. But still was curious of how many recursions would happen?

Question:
Add 2 numbers without using any arithmetic operations-
[image]

Comment: This question would be better if you took the time to type out and format the code section you care about rather than posting a picture. The picture is less readable and also impossible for people to copy and paste if they want to run it themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since carry is a&b shifted left, its bit-0 (least significant bit or LSB) is zero. Also, carry will have zero in each position p where b had zero in position p-1. This means that in the first recursive call, b will have a zero bit-0, and in the second recursive call, it will have zero in bit-0 and bit-1 (2 LSBs are zero), and so on. In the n-th recursive call, b will have n LSBs that are 0, so when n is the position of the most significant non-zero bit in a, carry will be zero, and the recursion will end in the next call.

So the time complexity is O(n), where n is the number of bits in a (more accurately, the position of the most significant non-zero bit in a, which in the worst case would be the number of bits in a). The space complexity is also O(n) because there are n recursive calls, but since this is tail recursion, it could be optimized away, so the optimized space complexity would be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

It's like a ripple carry adder (but it magically "knows" when the output is stable and take an early-out). With every step, the carry will have a strictly increasing position of the lowest set bit (infinity if there is no lowest set bit). So it can recurse at most once for each bit. How much time/space that represents depends on your assumptions (taking the number of bits as a constant gives useless results that prevent you from comparing it to alternative implementations).

It's clearly a tail call and it could be rewritten as a loop, so you could say it takes less space than if you pretended it actually used all that stack space.

Also, it's possible to do this in a number of steps logarithmic in the number of bits, similar to a Kogge-Stone adder.